# How can I run a large number of task with a defined degree of parallelism in C# using async / await?

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, async-await

I have a list of events and I'd like to fetch the performances for each event. Now I want to have a max of 10 'agents' that run in parallel and not more.

This is what the code would look like, except I want to make sure that these are not run **all** in parallel. There might be 1000s of elements in allEvents. I'd like to limit it to 10 in parallel at max.

```
    public async Task RefreshAll(Event[] allEvents)
    {
        var allPerformances = (await Task.WhenAll(allEvents.Select(CollectPerformancesForEvent))).SelectMany(x => x);
        // persist allPerformances
    }
    private async Task<Performance[]> CollectPerformancesForEvent(Event @event)
    {
        // some API call collecting all performances for @event...
        await Task.Delay(500);
        return new[]{ new Performance() };
    }
```

Comment: I've tried the solution described in the other question, they don't really apply here.
This questions is asking to delay the creation of tasks until they can actually be fulfilled.

Comment: Related: [How to limit the amount of concurrent async I/O operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806951/how-to-limit-the-amount-of-concurrent-async-i-o-operations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an extension method that will do exactly that

```
public static async Task<T[]> RunParallel<T>(this IEnumerable<Task<T>> tasks, int maxDegreeOfParallelism)
{
    var enumerationLock = new object();
    var parallelTasks = new List<Task>(maxDegreeOfParallelism);
    var results = new ConcurrentBag<T>();

    using (var enumerator = tasks.GetEnumerator())
    {
        // spin up just a few 'agents' to process the tasks
        await Task.WhenAll(Enumerable
            .Range(0, maxDegreeOfParallelism)
            .Select(_ => Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                Task<T> task;
                do
                {
                    // we need to make sure threads 'de-queue' without interferance
                    lock (enumerationLock)
                    {
                        // pick next element if available
                        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                        task = enumerator.Current;
                    }

                    // wait for task to finish and add aggregate results
                    results.Add(await task);
                } while (task != null);
            }))
        );
        // wait until all 'agents' are finished
        await Task.WhenAll(parallelTasks);
    }
    return results.ToArray();
}
```

Then you can change the call by simply using `RunParallel` and define the degree of parallelism:

```
var allPerformances = (await allEvents.Select(CollectPerformancesForEvent).RunParallel(10)).SelectMany(x => x);
```

Comment: Your approach is good, but the implementation is missing some features. On error is not failing fast, and the results are not in the same order as the tasks. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56862796/11178549) is a more complete implementation.